# What are these '@' symbol things in Web components [api, wire]?

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

While understanding code snippets provided by Salesforce. There are a few things which were confusing.
Like what is @api, @wire.

I googled for them, came to know they are called decorators. Responsible for 'import' things. Means wiring up the functionality with current logic.

I am actually finding what is the use of @api, @wire ...etc. Is it defined somewhere that where to use which decorators?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Decorators are nothing but annotations just like the one you use in
>   your apex class like @auraenabled which adds functionality to the
>   regular apex method to be able to be called from a lightning
>   component, but decorators here are annotations in the context of
>   javascript allowing them to provide functionality for properties or
>   functions!

There are 3 decorators specific to lightning web components:

**@api :**
To expose a public property(Think of properties as your aura attributes), decorate it with @api. Public properties define the API for a component. An owner component that uses the component in its markup can access the component’s public properties. Public properties are reactive. If the value of a reactive property changes, the component’s template rerenders any content that references the property.To expose a public method, decorate it with @api. Public methods are part of a component’s API. You can use a JavaScript method to communicate down the containment hierarchy. For example, an owner calls a method on a child component that it contains.

**@track :**
To track a private property’s value and rerender a component when it changes, decorate the property with @track. Tracked properties are also called private reactive properties.

**@wire :**
To read Salesforce data, Lightning web components use a reactive wire service. When the wire service provisions data, the component rerenders. Components use @wire in their JavaScript class to specify a wire adaptor or an Apex method.

There is lot more documentation you can read about decorators and how to use them in the [developer guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.reference_decorators) available in the component library.